# Phpstorm subversion: Cannot edit file: File "" is readonly, but miss svn:needs-lock property

Tags: php, svn, phpstorm

My PhpStorm project keeps warning me that my project is read-only, however I unchecked the read-only status, and it keeps giving me that error. I also did a get ownership on the folder!

Comment: Id this project shared via Dropbox or alike (Google Drive etc) ?

Comment: If the project is running in Vagrant (or other VM), the default share might interfere with read/writes (I had the problem with SVN 1.7). In all honesty though, you should consider binning SVN if possible. Most modern versioning systems will convert and maintain your history.